# Unable to make a loop roll successfully

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written some code in python in combination with selenium to grab some phone numbers from a website. To reach the content it is necessary to input city names in the searchbox and then hit the search button. I did it accordingly with "Miami" as city name. However, a list of names come up with hyperlink connected to each name. If the link is clicked then a information box pop up. My script can parse the phone number from it. The problem I'm facing is that there are around 30 names but my script only parses a single lead and instead of going for clicking the next  link it breaks. How can i rectify my loop to roll successfully and can parse all the leads?

This is the link I'm talking about [The Link](http://www.facdl.org/page/find-a-lawyer):

This is the script I've written so far:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
from selenium import webdriver;import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("put here the above link")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='city']"))).send_keys("Miami")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn-primary"))).click()
time.sleep(3)
try:
    for item in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ajaxBtn"))):
        item.click()
        time.sleep(3)
        root = fromstring(driver.page_source)
        phone = root.cssselect("td:contains('Phone:')+td")[0].text
        print(phone) #prints it and stops rolling
except:pass

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close the pop-up after reading the phone number so that it can find next element to click and open the pop-up. Also there is a case some record doesnt have phone and need to scroll to next item.

Just update the loop like below:

```
try:
    for item in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ajaxBtn"))):
        item.click()
        time.sleep(3)
        root = fromstring(driver.page_source)
        try:
            phone = root.cssselect("td:contains('Phone:')+td")[0].text
        except:
            print("No phone!")
            pass
        print(phone) #prints it and stops rolling
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#popclick > div > div > div.modal-header > button"))).click()
        # find the height of the item by item.location['y'] and scroll to the item
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, %d)" %(item.location['y']))
except:pass
```

Comment: Thanks Mesut GÜNEŞ for your solution. It perfectly does the job. Btw, could you please give me a oneliner explanation about what this line `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, %d)" %(item.location['y']))` does here. Thanks.

Comment: @Topto `item.location['y']` gives the height of web element, you can scroll to element by it heigth

Comment: One last thing to know on this as I do not come across an expert like you everyday. I used `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")` in my above script (not within the portion you rectified) to reach the search button, is it the proper way because sometimes it reaches the bottom of a page in other cases. Thanks.